# Experience issues with rdesktop and Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

For many sad reasons I have been combining my Linux desktop with a Windows session. I have been using a Windows Terminal Server with Gnome2/Mate and rdesktop like this:

```
rdesktop [...] -a 24 -x l -D -g 1920x1032+24+0 <windows_terminal_server>
```

In terms of user experience, this command would replace the background of one of my desktops with my Windows session.

I have a slightly different setup right now: There is no terminal server anymore. Instead, I have a Windows 8.1 pro VM on my computer.

I now face the problem that my Windows session runs at  very low quality. The resolution is what I set it too, but the mouse cursor is just white and the font is rendered poorly. Very much like I set the RDP parameters for a 56kbit connection. The interesting thing is that, at the login screen where I enter the password, the quality is as I would expect it. It's only my user session that reduces the "desktop experience".

On the other hand, when I connect using `remmina`, the quality settings in my user session are fine. However, rammina cannot do the smooth integration into my desktop as described above.

I want a desktop integration as described using rdesktop, but graphics quality as when using remmina. How can I achieve both?

---

**Edit 1**

The problem must be Windows 8.1 specific. I have another VM, which is a Windows Server 2008 R2. The RDP connection to this VM works as expected. Should I move this question to another SX portal?